# Child Class auto generates id when pushing data in firebase database

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to push data into by firebase database using angularjs. I used the system as the key and then the equipment as the child, but when i push the data it generates a key and under that it stores the equipment. I want it to store my data like so:

```
System -> Equipment1
       -> Equipment2
       -> Equipment3

System2 -> Equipment1
        -> Equipment2
        -> Equipment3
```

Here is my code:

```
/*global angular*/
var app = angular.module('input', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider.when('/input', {
        templateUrl: 'input/input.html',
        controller: 'inputCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('inputCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', function ($scope, $firebaseObject) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.system;
    $scope.message;
    $scope.writeUserData = function (equipment) {
        firebase.database().ref('data/' + $scope.system + '/equipments').push({
            equipment: equipment
  });
        $scope.message = "Success";
}
}]);
```

This is what it looks like after i push the data.

[image: Database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the name of the child node, don't call `push()`.

```
firebase.database().ref('data/' + $scope.system + '/equipments').set({
        equipment: equipment
});
```

But you'll want to probably give a name for the child node, e.g.

```
firebase.database().ref('data/' + $scope.system + '/equipments').child("Equipment1").set({
        equipment: equipment
});
```

Or

```
firebase.database().ref('data/' + $scope.system + '/equipments')
    .child(equipment).set(equipment);
```